# Javascript - remove all elements with the same class after the xth element

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I was simply trying to remove all elements with the same class after the 4th element found with just JS.

In jQuery this is simply:

```
$('.productListItem:nth-child(n+5)').remove();
```

I initially thought because .remove() is a basic Javascript function something like this might work, but it doesn't:

```
let element = document.querySelectorAll('.element:nth-child(n+5)');
element.remove();
```

I have found the solution below after some experimenting, to hopefully help others.

Comment: One big way that jquery differs from vanilla js is that jquery does operations on groups of elements ( like your selector that returns a bunch of elements followed by .remove() ) - in vanilla js you must individually operate on each element of a group as you discovered in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on the difference between jQuery & Javascript and reason behind why similar doesn't work. Most people don't explain that and even training I've gone through doesn't explain differences like that, and always just says if you know one you can easily translate to another language but that's not always the case with everything without extra explaining and work arounds. So again appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add this solution (that works to achieve this) for anyone else trying to find a work around to the same issue in JS:

```
let removeEl = document.querySelectorAll('.element');

for (let i = 4; i < removeEl.length; i++) { 
// replace the 4 with the index number of the last element you want to leave alone 
// and it will begin with all following elements found

    removeEl[i].remove(); 
    // or replace the .remove() with anything else you want to do with those elements 
    // being looped through

}
```

It might seem simple to some, but those jumping from jQuery like me, this wasn't the simplest thing to figure out. Googling didn't help and neither did a stack Overflow search for me as they all wanted to focus on removing from arrays after a certain index.

So I hope it helps others.